# How to join two sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 5 table

**title**

```
ID_title(pk)| nameTitle
-----------------------------
 t1     | Distance Examination
```

**list**

```
ID_list(pk)| nameList   |ID_unit |ID_title
-----------------------------------------
 l1    | Appearance | u1     | t1
```

**unit**

```
ID_unit(pk)| nameUnit
-----------------------------
 u1    | beats per min(bpm)
```

**choice**

```
ID_choice(pk)| nameChoice
-----------------------------
 c1    | Thoracoabdomen
```

**list_choice**

```
ID_list(pk)| ID_choice (pk) |Order_LiCh(pk)
--------------------------------------------
 l1    | c1 |1
```

**I don't know how to create result like this:**

```
ID_title| nameTitle    |ID_list| nameList   |ID_unit |nameUnit          |ID_choice| nameChoice|Order_LiCh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t1      | Milk Quality |l1     | Appearance | u1     |beats per min(bpm)| c1      |Thoracoabdomen||1
```

I have two sql queries
The first query:

```
SELECT title.ID_title
, title.nameTitle
, list.ID_list
, list.nameList
, list.ID_unit
, list.ID_title
, unit.ID_unit
, unit.nameUnit

FROM list
INNER JOIN title ON list.ID_title = title.ID_title 
INNER JOIN unit ON list.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
```

The second query:

```
 SELECT choice.ID_choice
, choice.nameChoice
, list_choice.ID_choice
, list_choice.ID_list
, list_choice.order_LiCh
, list.ID_list
, list.nameList
, list.ID_unit
, list.ID_title
FROM list_choice
INNER JOIN choice ON choice.ID_choice = list_choice.ID_choice
INNER JOIN list  ON list.ID_list = list_choice.ID_list
```

If you have any advice, please let me know.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: could try `SELECT title.ID_title
, title.nameTitle
, list.ID_list
, list.nameList
, list.ID_unit
, unit.nameUnit
, choice.ID_choice
, choice.nameChoice
, list_choice.order_LiCh

FROM list
INNER JOIN title ON list.ID_title = title.ID_title 
INNER JOIN unit ON list.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
INNER JOIN choice ON choice.ID_choice = list_choice.ID_choice
INNER JOIN list  ON list.ID_list = list_choice.ID_list`

Comment: @bio_sprite MySQL said: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'list'

Comment: `SELECT title.ID_title , title.nameTitle , list.ID_list , list.nameList , list.ID_unit , unit.nameUnit , choice.ID_choice , choice.nameChoice , list_choice.Order_LiCh FROM title INNER JOIN list ON list.ID_title = title.ID_title INNER JOIN unit ON unit.ID_unit = list.ID_unit INNER JOIN list_choice ON list_choice.ID_list = list.ID_list INNER JOIN choice ON choice.ID_choice = list_choice.ID_choice` should work.

Comment: as a note, in your example list_choice.ID_choice is 'appearance' but from your second query I gather it should be 'c1' for clearer understanding (else query does not work)

Comment: @bio_sprite It's works. Thank you for your help. :)